# SwitchListTile and Container or RaisedButton within ListView.builder not working properly

Tags: flutter

I have a **Dialog** class in which I want to show different designations that could be assigned to an employee.

In the beginning, I tried to use only a **RaisedButton** to select the desired designations. Within the App, the Button should change Colors. This part is found within a **StatefulWidget**.

I also tried a modified version, where I created a new **StatefulWidget** only for the **Dialog** part but this part did not have any effect, thus I thought to implement a **SwitchListTile** to do the same thing.

The **SwitchListTile** gets activated and deactivated although **only** the true value gets registered. This means that when I deactivate (swipe to left) the code does not go within the following **setState**:

`setState(() { hEnabled[hDesignations[index].designation] = value; });`

Also when the **hEnabled** Map gets changed within the **setState** method the following code does not re-run to change the color of the container:

`color: hEnabled[hDesignations[index].designation] ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,`

Part with the Dialog:

```
  Widget buildChooseDesignations(
      BuildContext context, List<Designation> hDesignations) {
    return Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.circular(8.0),
      ),
      child: _buildDialogChild(context, hDesignations),
    );
  }

  _buildDialogChild(BuildContext context, List<Designation> hDesignations) {
    //todo: when editing an employee I need the chosen designations (have to pass a list)
    Map<String, bool> hEnabled = new Map<String, bool>();
    for (var i = 0; i < hDesignations.length; i++) {
      hEnabled[hDesignations[i].designation] = false;
    }
    return Container(
      height: 200.0,
      //todo: width not working properly
      width: 50,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: hDesignations.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 10,
                          color: hEnabled[hDesignations[index].designation] 
                              ? Colors.green
                              : Colors.grey,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 80),
                          child: Text(hDesignations[index].designation,
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: SwitchListTile(
                            value: hEnabled[hDesignations[index].designation],
                            onChanged: (bool value) {
                              setState(() {
                                hEnabled[hDesignations[index].designation] =
                                    value;
                              });
                            }),
                      )
                    ],
                  );
                }),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 15.0,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.blueGrey,
            child: Text(
              'set',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              //todo: save the 'newly' selected designations in a list on set click
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

The Dialog is called when I click on the **Add +** FlatButton and looks like this:

```
ButtonTheme(
                      height: 30.0,
                      // child: Container(),
                      child: FlatButton(
                        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                        color: Colors.blueGrey.shade200,
                        onPressed: () {
                          //todo add Dialog
                          // List<Designation> hList = state.designations;
                          showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) => buildChooseDesignations(
                                  context, state.designations));
                          // DesignationDialog(
                          //      designations:state.designations));
                        },
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                        child: Text(
                          'Add +',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem :)

First I did re-write everything into a new **StatefulWidget**. This I needed since I want that my widget gets re-build after I click on the **SwitchListTile** to re-color my Container.

Then I had to move my **hEnabled** (re-named **hChecked**) map outside the state. The reason was that the widget would re-build all the everything including the initialization of this map, making the user's input useless.

The same applies to the **RaisedButton** Widget.

Here is my code:

```
class DesignationDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Designation> designations;

  final Map<String, bool> hChecked;

  DesignationDialog({Key key, this.designations, this.hChecked}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DesignationDialogState createState() => _DesignationDialogState();
}

class _DesignationDialogState extends State<DesignationDialog> {
  _buildDialogChild(BuildContext context, List<Designation> hDesignations) {
    //todo: when editing an employee I need the chosen designations (have to pass a list)
    // for (var i = 0; i < hDesignations.length; i++) {
    //   hChecked[hDesignations[i].designation] = false;
    // }
    return Container(
      height: 200.0,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: hDesignations.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  // return ButtonTheme(
                  //   //todo: fix the width of the buttons is not working
                  //   minWidth: 20,
                  //   child: RaisedButton(
                  //     color: widget.hChecked[hDesignations[index].designation]
                  //         ? Colors.green
                  //         : Colors.grey,
                  //     child: Text(hDesignations[index].designation),
                  //     onPressed: () {
                  //       //todo mark designation and add to an array
                  //       setState(() {
                  //         widget.hChecked[hDesignations[index].designation] =
                  //             !widget
                  //                 .hChecked[hDesignations[index].designation];
                  //       });
                  //     },
                  //   ),
                  // );

                  // -- With Switch
                  return Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Text(hDesignations[index].designation),
                          width: 10,
                          color: widget.hChecked[hDesignations[index].designation]
                              ? Colors.green
                              : Colors.grey,
                        )),
                         Expanded(
                        child: SwitchListTile(
                            value: widget.hChecked[hDesignations[index].designation],
                            onChanged: (bool value) {
                              setState(() {
                                widget.hChecked[hDesignations[index].designation] =
                                    value;
                              });
                            }),
                      )
                    ],
                  );
                  // -- end
                }),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 15.0,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.blueGrey,
            child: Text(
              'set',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              //todo: save the 'newly' selected designations in a list on set click
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.circular(8.0),
      ),
      child: _buildDialogChild(context, widget.designations),
    );
  }
```